# How to make a "leave" command?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make my discord bot leave a voice channel, but I can't find the right code, could you help me with that?
If it helps, here's my join command:

```
if (message.content === `${prefix}join`) {
  if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
    message.member.voiceChannel.join()
      .then(connection => { // Connection is an instance of VoiceConnection
        message.reply('I have successfully connected to the channel!');
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  } else {
    message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your bot leave a voice channel by using [`voiceChannel.leave()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=leave). `message.guild.me.voiceChannel` is the voice channel of the bot if it's connected to any. If the bot isn't connected to a voice channel it will return `undefined`.

**Example:**
Using the leave command will make the bot check if it's connected to a voice channel and if yes, leave it.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "leave")) {
  // check if the bot is connected to a voice channel
  if (message.guild.me.voiceChannel !== undefined) {
    message.guild.me.voiceChannel.leave();
    message.reply("I have successfully left the voice channel!");
  } else {
    message.reply("I'm not connected to a voice channel!");
  }
}
```